# Поменять местами блоки c помощью jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

Здравствуйте

При создании опроса пользователь может изменить порядок вывода вариантов ответа. Происходит это при нажатии на кнопку вверх или вниз.

Пытаюсь реализовать это, но пока увы... Не работает сам jquery/

**ОБНОВЛЕНО**

**polls/new.html.haml**

```
%h1= title "Новый опрос"
= simple_form_for @poll do |f|
  = f.error_messages header_message: nil
  = f.input :question, disabled: !@poll.editable?(current_user), input_html: { class: 'input-block-level' }
  = f.input :results_hidden, as: :boolean, inline_label: 'Скрыть результаты до окончания опроса', label: false
  = f.input :from_date, as: :datetime, input_html: { class: 'poll_date' }
  = f.input :to_date, as: :datetime, input_html: { class: 'poll_date' }
  %h3#poll-items Варианты ответа (не больше пяти)
  .item_index  
    = f.simple_fields_for :poll_items do |poll|
      = render 'poll_item_fields', f: poll
    = link_to_add_association 'Добавить еще вариант', f, :poll_items
    .form-actions
      = f.button :submit, 'Опубликовать опрос', class: 'btn-bg'
      %p 
        Вернуться к посту:
        = link_to @owner
```

Это мои вьюшки

**poll_fields.html.haml**

```
%h3#poll-items Варианты ответа (не больше пяти)
.item_index  
  = f.fields_for :poll_items do |poll|
    = render "poll_item_fields", f: poll
  .links
    = link_to_add_association 'Добавить еще вариант', f, :poll_items, render_options: {class: 'links'}
```

**poll_item_fields.html.haml**

```
.poll_row
  .poll_item
    = f.input :answer, input_html: { class: 'ctrlenter expanding' }, label: false, placeholder: 'Введите вариант ответа'
    = link_to 'вверх', 'javascript:;', input_html: { class: 'up' }
    = link_to 'вниз', 'javascript:;', input_html: { class: 'down' } 
    = link_to_remove_association "удалить", f, { wrapper_class: 'poll_item' }
```

При нажатии вверх должен блок с "poll_row" меняться местами с верхним блоком, аналогично и при нажатии вниз.

Реализовал следующим образом, но к сожалению не работает:

**poll_item.js**

```
(document).ready(function(){
    $(".up").click(function(){
      var pdiv = $(this).parent('poll_row');
      pdiv.insertBefore(pdiv.prev());

      return false
    });

    $(".down").click(function(){
       var pdiv = $(this).parent('poll_row');
       pdiv.insertAfter(pdiv.next());

       return false
    });
});
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: При чем здесь ruby в метках? И разместите пожалуйста в тексте вопроса кусок HTML. Не все могут обрабатывать шаблоны в голове.

Comment: @newman это может быть затруднительно, т. к. в шаблоне используются функции-хелперы из фреймворка. Они в чистый HTML не переводятся. Да, это означает, что тут нужны навыки сразу и Rails, и front-end'а. Да, это плохо, это далеко от минимального примера. Но что поделать.

Comment: @D-side, для начала можно открыть исходник страницы в браузере и скопировать фрагметн оттуда. Это будет  полезней кусков шаблона.

Comment: @newman тогда уж проще совсем оторвать вопрос от Rails и посвятить реализации изменения порядка следования input'ов в форме. Вот это уже был бы конструктив. Посмотрим, что думает автор :)

Comment: @D-side поэтому я и спрашивал, в своем первом комментарии, причем здесь Ruby  По сути вопрос сводится к тому что некорректно используются селекторы в jQuery. Или ошибка в структуре HTML. А без готового HTML ошибку не локализовать.

Comment: @newman возможно, кстати, что ошибка при этом **всплывёт** и проявится отношение к Rails. Т. к. [параметр `input_html`, насколько я знаю, с `link_to` не используется](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to). Возможно, в этом и дело. В любом случае, ждём автора.

Comment: Извините, обновил вопрос: добавил полностью представление polls/new.html.erb. Я думаю этого должно быть предостаточно.

Comment: да все верно, haml, на автомате уже пишу erb

Comment: Вы бы ответ посмотрели. :)

Comment: да, уже смотрю. Спасибо  ребята за помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Боюсь предположить что так

```js
$(function(){
 $('.rows :button[value=down]').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').insertAfter($(this).closest('.row').next());
 });
 $('.rows :button[value=up]').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').insertBefore($(this).closest('.row').prev());
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rows">
  <div class="row">
   <input type="text" name="" id="" value="text-1">
   <input type="button" value="up">
   <input type="button" value="down">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <input type="text" name="" id="" value="text-2">
   <input type="button" value="up">
   <input type="button" value="down">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <input type="text" name="" id="" value="text-3">
   <input type="button" value="up">
   <input type="button" value="down">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <input type="text" name="" id="" value="text-4">
   <input type="button" value="up">
   <input type="button" value="down">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <input type="text" name="" id="" value="text-5">
   <input type="button" value="up">
   <input type="button" value="down">
  </div>
 </div>
```