# Как увеличить/уменьшить value скрытого поля с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку вверх или вниз, блок `poll_row` должен поменяться местами с соседним, а также увеличиться или уменьшится атрибут `value` на `+1` или `-1` скрытого поля с классом `sequence`.

Сами блоки меняются, но вот как изменить атрибут `value`, не получается. Также как сделать, чтобы автоматом менялось значение `value` из соседнего блока с которым произошел обмен соответственно на `+1` или `-1`.

```
<div class="poll_row">
    <input class="poll_item", type="text, value='text1'>
    <input class="sequence"  type="hidden" value="1">
    <button class="up_id" name="button" type="button" value="вверх">вверх</button>
    <button class="down_id" name="button" type="button" value="вниз">вниз</button>
</div>


<div class="poll_row">
    <input class="poll_item", type="text, value='text2'>
    <input class="sequence"  type="hidden" value="2">
    <button class="up_id" name="button" type="button" value="вверх">вверх</button>
    <button class="down_id" name="button" type="button" value="вниз">вниз</button>
</div>


<div class="poll_row">
    <input class="poll_item", type="text, value='text3'>
    <input class="sequence"  type="hidden" value="3">
    <button class="up_id" name="button" type="button" value="вверх">вверх</button>
    <button class="down_id" name="button" type="button" value="вниз">вниз</button>
</div>
```

Написал след. функцию, но почему то атрибут `value` не меняется:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


 $(document).on('click', '.down_id', function() {

    var seq_field = $(this).prev('.sequence');
    var seq_val = parseInt(seq_field.attr('value'));
    seq_field.attr('value', seq_val + 1);
    $(this).closest('.poll_row').insertAfter($(this).closest('.poll_row').next());
  });

  $(document).on('click','.up_id', function() {
    var seq_field = $(this).prev('.sequence');
    var seq_val = parseInt(seq_field.attr('value'));
    seq_field.attr('value', seq_val - 1);
    $(this).closest('.poll_row').insertBefore($(this).closest('.poll_row').prev());
  });
});
```

Comment: само значение `$('.sequence').val(parseFloat($('.sequence').val()) + 1)` а поменять местами вы уже [спрашивали тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498740/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery/498788#498788)

Comment: да, спрашивал. Спасибо за ваш ответ. Не понятно а куда эту строку кода вставить? Как мне достучаться до  моего текущего $('.sequence'),  а не всех сразу?

Comment: $('.sequence').val(parseFloat($('.sequence').val()) + 1) - изменится у всех +1. А нужно только у конкретного

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну тогда так.

```js
$(function(){
 $(document).on('click', '.down_id', function() {
  $(this).siblings('.sequence').val(parseFloat( $(this).siblings('.sequence').val() ) + 1);
  $(this).parent().next().children('.sequence').val( $(this).parent().next().children('.sequence').val() - 1);
  $(this).closest('.poll_row').insertAfter($(this).closest('.poll_row').next());
 });

 $(document).on('click','.up_id', function() {
  $(this).siblings('.sequence').val(parseFloat( $(this).siblings('.sequence').val() ) -1);
     $(this).parent().prev().children('.sequence').val(parseFloat($(this).parent().prev().children('.sequence').val())+ 1);
  $(this).closest('.poll_row').insertBefore($(this).closest('.poll_row').prev());
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="poll_row">
    <input class="poll_item" type="text" value='text1'>
    <input class="sequence"  type="hidden" value="1">
    <button class="up_id" name="button" type="button" value="вверх">вверх</button>
    <button class="down_id" name="button" type="button" value="вниз">вниз</button>
</div>


<div class="poll_row">
    <input class="poll_item" type="text" value='text2'>
    <input class="sequence"  type="hidden" value="2">
    <button class="up_id" name="button" type="button" value="вверх">вверх</button>
    <button class="down_id" name="button" type="button" value="вниз">вниз</button>
</div>


<div class="poll_row">
    <input class="poll_item" type="text" value='text3'>
    <input class="sequence"  type="hidden" value="3">
    <button class="up_id" name="button" type="button" value="вверх">вверх</button>
    <button class="down_id" name="button" type="button" value="вниз">вниз</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое. немного не корректно работает. Если меняю третий со вторым, у третьего становится значенние 0, второй: 2, первый: 1.

Comment: ну так допиши строку по примеру `$(this).parent().children('.sequence').val(parseFloat($('.sequence').val()) + 1);` изгачально надо было сразу писать все требования.

Comment: пока с js на "Вы". Если по вашему примеру, как мне найти элемент с которым я меняюсь и отнять или прибавить его скрытому полу единицу? Извините, если совсем глупые вопросы.

Comment: получается, алгоритм следующий меняю значение в поле которое хочу поднять/опутить, дальше нахожу первое поле которое идет после текущего, меняю у него?

Comment: вернее меняю также у всех, которые находятся у всех которые идут после текущего. Если не ошибаюсь так:  '$(this).parent().children('.sequence').next('.sequence').val(parseInt($('.sequence').val()) - 1);'

Comment: @StefanHansch Обновил ответ. учи итить js

Comment: спасибо, учу, разбираюсь...

Comment: если можно, последний вопрос: а с чем может быть связано что в моем случае только когда второй раз нажимаю кнопку, меняются местами поля. Но когда первый раз нажал кнопку, меняются только value скрытого поля.

Comment: страно, в вашем примере тоже почему то когда нажимаю тольок второй раз накнопку меняются поля местами.

Comment: разобрался, спасибо большое!